# Dart List negative indexing does not work

Tags: dart

Dart's `List` Structure doesn't seem to support negative indexing. What is the reasoning behind this? Every other language I have ever used supports this. Why did dart decide to exclude such a basic construct?

The following code -

```
void main() {
    List<String> x = ["foo", "bar"];
    print(x[-1]);
}
```

Produces -

```
Uncaught exception:
RangeError (index): Index out of range: index must not be negative: -1
```

Comment: "Every other language I have ever used supports this." No language I have ever used supports this. Why should it? There will never be an element below index `0`. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: That's weird, negative indexing is a widely known thing. It simply allows one to access indices starting from the last element, instead of first. I guess I've been in the echo chamber too much? It's just a nice-to-have I guess...

Comment: *Every other language I have ever used supports this.* What was *every* that? PHP? Also you know that there is a difference between array[-1] and array["-1"] right?

Comment: @DevAggarwal its so widely know that I never heard of it. (so at most its not that wide)

Comment: Yes, I was influenced too much by Python's magic -- tricked me into believing that it was a widely supported thing!

Comment: @Antoniossss It's wide because Python is one of the few high-level languages that is popular because it's quality and intuitive. Something we cannot say about Dart that is far younger and feels old as hell. Without  Google's Flutter, it would end up where it should. Nowhere..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Dart does not support negative indexes.

To access elements relative to the end, you can calculate the index using

```
print(x[x.length - 1])
```

You can create a feature request in https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk to get feedback from the language designers.

Comment: I'm not sure the original reasoning is still known. It was likely just not considered worth it. Allowing negative indices can hide errors. If you didn't intende the index to be negative, your could should just have crashed, but by being generous about invalid arguments, the code actually becomes less safe. Also, if you allow this in one place, you should allow it evertwhere (or only allow it in a specific construct, like a "slice" operator, which Dart does not have). That adds an overhead to all index-based operations, giving you larger code when deploying to, say, JavaScript.

Comment: "Dart does not support negative indexes." "...a slice-operator, which Dart does not have" 
Says a lot about yet another new language trying to be the cool kid...

Answer (score 7):

To print the last element, you can simply use:

`print(x.last);`